# main.c:7:1 error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: c

i am writing a program in c code that is designed to return a letter grade based on the numerical value you enter but it returns the same error every time, which i can't seem to figure out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char lettergrade(float numgrade);

int main(void);
{
    float numgrade;
    char grade;

    printf(" what is your numerical grade? ");
    scanf("%f", &numgrade);

    grade = lettergrade (numgrade);

    printf("here is your letter grade: %c ", grade);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

char lettergrade(float numgrade);
{
    if (numgrade < 50)
    {
        lettergrade = 'D';
    }
    if (numgrade <= 50 && numgrade < 65)
    {
        lettergrade = 'C';
    }
    if (numgrade <= 65 && numgrade < 80)
    {
        lettergrade = 'B';
    }
    if (numgrade >= 80)
    {
        lettergrade = 'A';
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `int main(void);` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: already tried that, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @MarcusGilchrist Does the error still point to the same line, or does it now point to the other place where you made that mistake?

Comment: `return` is not a function. `(0)` is just a funny way to write `0`.

Comment: I'm new to c code so pardon my lack of strength in the subject, but @ChristianGibbons but it actually says neither, it gave me a new error instead saying expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/tQ8vt2).

Comment: In addition to what Christian said, you don't set the return value by assigning to the function name. You declare a local variable, assign to that, and then do return varname;  (or just return the characters immediately)

Comment: @Ray yeah i realized the error now, was just confused as to what i was doing wrong but thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same mistake twice:

1. `char lettergrade(float numgrade);...`-->`char lettergrade(float numgrade)...{}`
2. `int main(void); ...`-->`int main(void) ...{}`

But beside that, you code has other errors these two masked :-(

`lettergrade = 'D';` is not legal since `lettergrade`  is the function name (and therefore is not an *"lvalue"* which means you can't assign a value to it), and it should be a variable in this context. change to something like:

```
char lettergrade(float numgrade)
{
    char tmp;
    if (numgrade < 50)
    {
        tmp = 'D';
    }
    if (numgrade <= 50 && numgrade < 65) // also, this probably should be if (numgrade >= 50 && ...
    {
        tmp = 'C';
    }
    if (numgrade <= 65 && numgrade < 80) // same goes here
    {
        tmp = 'B';
    }
    if (numgrade >= 80)
    {
        tmp = 'A';
    }

    // return tmp 
    /* consider returning tmp, since always returning (0) 
       makes this whole function redundant (your current 
       function just returns 0, no matter what the input is) */
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes `return tmp;` but you have no default value. The conditionals can be simplified by the use of `else` because each grade value is being tested twice.

Comment: i see now what you mean by the redundancy of always returning 0 but im confused by what you mean there is no default value?

Comment: `if (numgrade < 50) { tmp = 'D'; } else if (numgrade < 65) { tmp = 'C'; } else if (numgrade < 80) { tmp = 'B'; } else { tmp = 'A'; }` . Note that some of your conditionals were the wrong sense, for example `numgrade <= 50` should have been `numgrade >= 50`, but I have side-stepped that.

Comment: @MarcusGilchrist yes (to the deleted "any glaring errors?"): not checking the return value from `scanf("%f", &numgrade);` which is the number of items successfully converted. `float numgrade;` was *uninitialised* so if `scanf` fails you will pass garbage to the function.

Comment: @MarcusGilchrist not sure what you mean. Do you want to add a default value in case all of your condition are false? If so just add another else, and assign `tmp` with your default value, and then return it. If this is not what you mean, please explain

Comment: Sorry, I think that that was because of my first comment ;) I realise this is your answer so I gave UV.

Comment: @CIsForCookies yes that was what i was asking, thank you. Weather Vane merely trying to save the embarrassment actually;) but thanks for the help guys, its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(void);
```

^ Function declaration.

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

^ Function definition; function body goes between `{` `}`.

```
int main(void); { ... }
```

^ Syntax error; can't have both `;` and `{` `}`.